# Minimize specific regular expression

Tags: regex

I have the following regex

```
(1*)+(1*0)(ε+11*0)*(11*)
```

If minimized, it should be

```
(1+01)*
```

But I cannot understand the minimization, could somebody explain it?

Comment: What does ε denote here?

Comment: it denotes an empty string

Comment: They aren't the same, the long one can match at least `01` but the short one can match nothing or `101`

Comment: the short one can match 01 too, you are missing the `+` which is an or

Comment: @Toto Is right, they aren't identical ...! Take a look at [this](https://regex101.com/r/eX4tC9/2) and [this](https://regex101.com/r/eX4tC9/1)

Comment: @AndiPavllo: I guess you aren't using usual regex, `+` is a quantifier that means one or more times the preceeding character.

Comment: @Shafizadeh et al - this question uses the traditional Computer Science notation for regular expressions. This is different from regex languages used in many programming languages - see my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, for other people watching this, this is traditional formal Computer science regular expressions, not the regex languages used in most programming languages. In programming language regex terms, the two expressions would be `1*|1*0(|11*0)*11*` and `(1|01)*`.

---

Now, to the problem:

The initial expression has `1*` at the front and back of the expression in both of the top-level alternatives. So we can rewrite it first as:

```
(1*)(ε+0(ε+11*0)*1)(1*)
```

Now, in general, `(ε+x)*` for any regular expression `x` is just `x*`. So that's:

```
(1*)(ε+0(11*0)*1)(1*)
```

Now, also `x*` is the same as `ε+xx*`, so we can expand that inner bit out:

```
(1*)(ε+0(ε+(11*0)(11*0)*)1)(1*)
```

And now apply `a(x+y)b` => `axb+ayb`:

```
(1*)(ε+01+0(11*0)(11*0)*1)(1*)
```

Now, apply `(xy)*x` => `x(yx)*`:

```
(1*)(ε+01+0(11*0)1(1*01)*)(1*)
```

And rearrange the parens:

```
(1*)(ε+01+(01)(1*)(01)(1*(01))*)(1*)
```

And factor out a common prefix:

```
(1*)(ε+(01)(ε+(1*(01))(1*(01))*))(1*)
```

Using an expansion we had before, but in reverse:

```
(1*)(ε+(01)(1*(01))*)(1*)
```

Now bring that left `1*` in:

```
((1*)+(1*)(01)(1*(01))*)(1*)
```

Since `1*` is the same as `ε+1*`, we can write this as:

```
((ε+1*)+(1*)(01)(1*(01))*)(1*)
```

Rearranging alternatives:

```
(1*+(ε+(1*)(01)(1*(01))*))(1*)
```

Applying that `ε+xx*` <=> `x*` equivalence again:

```
(1*+(1*(01))*)(1*)
```

Now, `x*+(x*y)*` can be shown equivalent to `(x+y)*` - applying that here gives:

```
(1+01)*(1*)
```

And now we just apply `(x+y)*x*` => `(x+y)*`, and we're done.

```
(1+01)*
```

---

Okay, trying to work out a simpler derivation. First off, I need you to accept these identities, where `x`, `y`, `a`, and `b` are arbitrary regular expressions:

1. `(ab)*a` <=> `a(ba)*`
2. `xa+ya` <=> `(x+y)a`
3. `ε+xx*`  <=> `x*`
4. `a*(ba*)*` <=> `(a+b)*`

As an aside, the last identity is often useful in constructing regexes that efficiently match grammars like strings with backslash escapes, where a naive approach might be `([^\\"]|\\.)*`, but it's much more efficient in most regex matching libraries to use `[^\\"]*(\\.[^\\"]*)*`. Anyway, to the problem:

```
(1*)+(1*0)(ε+11*0)*(11*)
```

Well, `(ε+x)*` is still the same as `x*`, so let's do that first:

```
(1*)+(1*0)(11*0)*(11*)
```

Now apply identity 2 and pull the `1*` out to the right:

```
(ε+(1*0)(11*0)*1)(1*)
```

Now, identity 1:

```
(ε+(1*0)1(1*01)*)(1*)
```

That's now ready for identity 3:

```
(1*01)*(1*)
```

Identity 1 again gives us:

```
1*((01)1*)*
```

And now identity 4 gives us the desired result:

```
(1+01)*
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks! I'm just wondering if there is a shorter way to minimize it :)

Comment: I think there is, looking at it again. However, I need to go take care of something now. I'll be back with a shorter path later, assuming that you'll accept that `x(yx)*y` is equivalent to `xy(xy)*`.

Comment: @AndiPavllo I added a shorter path

Comment: @DanielMartin just one small thing. How can `a*(ba*)` <=> `(a+b)*`? The first one doesn't accept `bb` but the second one does. Perhaps it's `a*(ba)*` <=> `(a+b)*`?